# Can't set textSize TextView by strings.xml in my Android project

Tags: java, android

When I set `android:textSize` as a hard string e.g. **50dp** my program works great, but if I save this size in ***strings.xml*** and use it like `android:textSize="@string/my_size"` I get many of errors.

Could anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: just use unit sp not dp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dimens.xml write

```
 <dimen name="my_size">16sp</dimen>
```

and use:

```
android:textSize="@dimen/my_size"
```

Comment: @user3616181 it's your choice. But I recommend to use dp for layout sizes, and sp for font size.

Comment: Can I notice some difference between this two units or is it just name convention?

Comment: Thank you very much for help of all you guys :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of using **strings.xml** to store values you should rather use **res/values/dimens.xml** to store values for the text size like this:

```
<dimen name="txtsize">50sp</dimen>
```

**NOTE:** instead of using ***dp***  you should use ***sp*** for text size.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the value in dimens.xml NOT in strings.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="font_size">50dp</dimen>
</resources>
```